# ordering a list using column names that aren't hardcoded in R

Tags: r

I have a list that I would like to reorder based on certain.

If I hard code the column names I get what I want.

```
tab <- tab[ order( tab$inclass , tab$childage , tab$region, tab$line ) , ]
```

I am trying to generalize the code so that I can use column names that aren't hard coded (my cuchars variable), and one constant column line.

```
cuchars <- c('inclass','childage','region')
```

What I tried is

```
tab2<- tab[ order( do.call(paste0,list('tab$',c(cuchars,'line'),collapse=', ') ) ) , ]
```

but it is deleting all of the data except for the first line.

Why is this happening? How can I fix the code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach:

```
tab[do.call(order, tab[c(cuchars, "line")]), ]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be changing the order. If I use tab[order(c(cuchars,'line'))] then the order changes, but I am loosing the rest of the columns in the list. Is there a way to keep all the columns and reorder them?

Comment: @Elks The code should be working. Can you provide a small reproducible example?

Comment: Sorry, you are right it is working. I was accidentally expecting something differnet.